# Number of positive odd divisors of a number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Then find the number of divisors of $210n$ that are odd multiples of $3$. Then answer must be in terms of $n$.

My attempt:
We have $210=2\times 3\times 5\times 7.$ The odd multiples of $3$ dividing $210$ are $$3, 15, 21, 105.$$ Let $x$ be the odd divisor of $n$. Then, the divisors of $210n$ that are odd multiples of $3$ are odd multiples of $A\times x$, where $A$ is an odd multiple of $3$ dividing $210$.

Please help how to write the answer in terms of $n$

Comment: For $n=1, 2$, $A$ is $1$, for $n=3$, $A$ is $3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be a positive integer who when written in prime factorization form is $X=p_1^{x_1}p_2^{x_2}p_3^{x_3}\cdots p_k^{x_k}$

The number of positive integer divisors of $X$ is equal to $(x_1+1)(x_2+1)\cdots (x_k+1)$

This is seen by straightforward counting principles... having chosen a value for the exponent for $p_1$ to be used for our divisor from among the integers $\{0,1,\dots,x_1\}$, chosen a value for the exponent for $p_2$ and so on, noting that there are $x_1+1$ such choices for $p_1$ since we are including zero.

Letting instead $X=2^{x_1}\cdot 3^{x_2}\cdot 5^{x_3}\cdot 7^{x_4}p_5^{x_5}p_6^{x_6}\cdots p_k^{x_k}$, explicitly including $2,3,5,7$ even if that makes $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ zero... we get that $$210X = 2^{x_1+1}\cdot 3^{x_2+1}\cdot 5^{x_3+1}\cdot 7^{x_4+1}p_5^{x_5}\cdots p_k^{x_k}$$

Now, counting the number of divisors of $210X$ who are odd (*meaning the exponent chosen for the divisor for $2$ must be zero*) who are multiples of $3$ (*meaning the exponent chosen for the divisor for $3$ must not be zero*)... the total will be:

$$(x_2+1)(x_3+2)(x_4+2)(x_5+1)(x_6+1)\cdots (x_k+1)$$

noting again that there is no freedom in our selection for the power of $2$ to use and that since this is $210X$ as opposed to $X$ itself, there is additional freedom for the choices of powers to be used for $3,5,7$

The answer depends on the exact prime factorization of $X$ and as such is unable to be simplified further without additional constraints on what $X$ is (*e.g. $X$ being coprime to $210$ in which case you might be able to write the answer in terms of $\sigma_0(X)$, the divisor counting function*)